# Command line / Terminal error on macOS Mojave

Tags: xcode, macos, terminal

After updating to macOS Mojave, on my terminal error shows up as :

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path
>   (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:
>   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

Answer (score 1):

`xcode-select --install`

Try this command, and if it doesn't work. Please try this!

`sudo xcode-select -switch /`

Answer (score 0):

**xcode-select --install**

Try running this code and it will install necessary x-code updates

Answer (score 0):

First open the Terminal, then type the following

```
xcode-select --install
```

the xcode will be installed after you approved the license agreements.